# Weird behavior with Print Statements in Java

Tags: java

This is a weird thing I ran into while trying to make a game in Java. When I run this as an implementation of the run method in the Runnable interface it gives me a blank screen with no output of the console

```
public void run() {
    //Grabs the last time from the CPU in nano-seconds
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    //Amount of ticks that we want per second
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    //Time alloted for one tick in nano-seconds for optimal performance
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    //Change in time from the CPU to check how overloaded it is
    double delta = 0;
    //Used to calculate FPS
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0 ;

    /*  Game loop use:
     *      From timer calls to while loops to recursive function calls to keep the game alive 
     *      Until a certain condition is meet (The loop)
     * 
     *      A way to delay the length of each loop iteration so you get a stable frame rate (The timing mechanism) 
     *  
     *      A way to make the game speed remain independent of the speed of the loop (The interpolation)*/

    //This is a variable timestep loop
    while (running) {
        //Grabs current time
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        //The change from now to lasttime divided by the the optiaml time for ticks 
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        //If the change is greater than 1, that means the mimimum time for a tick has been reached and it can call the tick method
        while (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            //Resets delta
            delta--;
        }
        //If game is running call the render method
        if(running)
            render();
        frames++;


        //If more than a second has passed in the CPU, print the number of frames and reset all values for the next second
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
            //While times updated per second is greater than one (allowing updates to be seen) call tick method of Handler class


            /* Fixed timestep loops vs Variable timestep loops:
             * 
             *      Variable timestep loops: Great because the game will seem consistent regardless of how fast the players's computer is
             *          Allowing it to work on a variety of machines and update the game logic with very high attention to details happening in the game 
             *          Graphics latency is not a problem as things are drawn as they change
             * 
             *      
             *    
             *      Fixed timestep loops: You know that every single timestep 
             *          will take up the exact same length of time. Allows for consistent gameplay 
             *          regardless of how fast a machine is as you know the tick rate of your machine
             *          Works wonderfully for math-heavy games with physics operations. Also good for networked games as packets are going and coming at a generally constant speed.
             *          Keeps game logic running at a very low rate while the frame rate can still and frame rate really high 
             *                                                            */
        }
    } 
    stop();
```

However, by adding a print statement that prints out the integer timer, I'm able to display a green screen (which I want) and the FPS is being displayed to the console.

Thoughts???

Comment: What sort of output were you expecting without print statements?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains nowhere like enough information to understand what is actually happening.  (Please consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

However, this sounds like a typical problem when multiple threads are involved, and one thread is updating stared state without adequate synchronization.

> Thoughts???

Well ... the standard i/o stream stacks have internal synchronization so that (for example) multiple threads writing to System.out doesn't cause corruption.

This synchronization can lead to cache flushes for other memory address, and alter the behavior of an *incorrectly implemented* multi-threaded application.  Hence, adding `print` statements can make things work in mysterious ways.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it or no?

Comment: Sure, you can fix your code so that you don't need the print statements to make it work.  But we can't help you find the bugs in your code without a minimal reproducible example.  See the link in my answer.